# Positioning multi-robot on static map

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, static-map, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I make a package with two Turtlebots and share a static map on Gazebo. My problem is that I can positionning Turtlebots where I want on a static global map.

I use GMapping and MoveBase and I try to make an exploration of an unknown environment.

When I use AMCL, turtlebots move between the center of the map and the real robot's position.

Is it possible to initialise the position of each Turtlebot on static map, and how ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131716/positioning-multi-robot-on-static-map/) by [Zephyrin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11981/zephyrin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL has initial_pose parameters. These parameters may help you to initialise the pose of robots.

~initial_pose_x (double, default: 0.0 meters) 
~initial_pose_y (double, default: 0.0 meters) 
~initial_pose_a (double, default: 0.0 radians)
~initial_cov_xx (double, default: 0.5*0.5 meters) 

~initial_cov_yy (double, default: 0.5*0.5 meters)
~initial_cov_aa (double, default: (π/12)*(π/12) radian)

http://wiki.ros.org/amcl

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zephyrin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11981/zephyrin/) on 2014-02-24**:
Thank, I use these config at first. But with this, my robot was jumping between the center of static map and his real position.
I made an exploration of unknown environment so I need a stable robot which doesn't jump.
Do you think if I plublish on the initialpose topics it can help me to fixe it ?